# Croogo/CakePHP: Plugin: OnActivation problem - cannot create tables from Schema and table-entry (via Model-instance) at the same time

Tags: cakephp, plugins, schema

I am currently working on an existing plugin, mostly successful at 
 extending it according to my wishes. But I ran into one major problem: 
 When activating the plugin (onActivation-method) for the first time, 
 the required tables have to be created, in case they do not exist. In 
 fact, they ARE created, it works properly. But directly afterwards, I 
 am creating an Instance of the plugin's Model in order to save a first 
 Model entry in one of the recently created tables. However, this does 
 not work. The tables are created, but I am getting an SQL-Error: 
 Croogo/CakePHP claims, that those tables do not exist. But they 
 actually do. If i hit refresh several times, the plugin gets 
 deacivated again. The tables are then already existing, and the next 
 activation is successful: The sample-data is entered.

This doe snot seem to be a caching issue, because I already playd 
 around with that. I also tried to use loadModel instead of 
 ClassRegistry. But that doesnt change anything at all.

Here is my code:

```
class SitesActivation {
public function beforeActivation(&$controller) {
    return true;
}

public function onActivation(&$controller) {
    App::import('Model', 'CakeSchema');
    App::import('Model', 'ConnectionManager');
    App::import('Libs', 'Sites.sites');
    include_once(APP.'plugins'.DS.'sites'.DS.'config'.DS.'schema'.DS.'schema.php');
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

    //Get all available tables
    $tables = $db->listSources();

    $CakeSchema = new CakeSchema();
    $SiteSchema = new SitesSchema();

    if (!in_array('sites', $tables)) {
        $db->execute($db->createSchema($SiteSchema, 'sites'));
    }
    if (!in_array('site_domains', $tables)) {
        $db->execute($db->createSchema($SiteSchema, 'site_domains'));
    }
    if (!in_array('sites_nodes', $tables)) {
        $db->execute($db->createSchema($SiteSchema, 'sites_nodes'));
    }

    //Insert "ALL SITES"

    $Site = ClassRegistry::init('Sites.Site');
    $Site->create();
    $data = array(
        'Site' => array(
            'id' => Sites::ALL_SITES,
            'title' => 'All Sites',
            'tagline' => Configure::read('Site.tagline'),
            'email' => Configure::read('Site.email'),
            'locale' => Configure::read('Site.locale'),
            'status' => Configure::read('Site.status'),
            'timezone' => Configure::read('Site.timezone'),
            'theme' => Configure::read('Site.theme'),
            'default' => 1,
        ),
        'SiteDomain' => array(
            'site_id' => Sites::ALL_SITES,
            'domain' => env('HTTP_HOST'),
        ),
    );
    $Site->saveAll($data);

    /*$db->execute($db->rawQuery(
        'INSERT INTO sites ( id, title, tagline, email, locale, status, timezone, theme, default ) VALUES( 
        "1",
        "All Sites",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.tagline') . '",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.email') . '",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.locale') . '",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.status') . '",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.timezone') . '",
        "' . Configure::read('Site.theme') . '",
        "1"
        )'
    ));*/
}

public function beforeDeactivation(&$controller) {
    return true;
}

public function onDeactivation(&$controller) {
}

}
```

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like cake has cached what tables exist and after you create new ones the cache is not updated.

There is a way to create a model instance without using cache, or to just clear the cache before creating the instance.

Check out the api docs for a bit more info on this

Comment: Thank your verymuch for answer, I really appreciate your help. "There is a way to create a model instance without using cache" - intersting point, I've been searching Google, the API docs and several cake-support sites for hours, and I really didnt find anything that helped me out. I tried Cache::clear(), tried to set cacheQueries and cacheSources false. I also tried to delete the cache files on runtime. Nothing seemed to work, except for $db->cacheSources = false, which resolved in a PHP-Error, but all the database-entries were written. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if $db->cacheSources is false cache is not checked, https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/model/datasources/datasource.php#L227 you can set this on the fly. the last part of your question does not make much sense so its hard to help you more

Comment: Thank you very much, $db->cacheSources = false really did it, it did it before. The PHP Error came from my very own stupidity, I tried to save a hasMany-Relationship without any indexed key. My fault :P